# Can't enter text in certain input fields on IE7

Tags: css, forms, input, internet-explorer-7

I have a site with a search box that works fine in all browsers except IE7.  Other textfields from the same site appear to work.  Here is an example page:

http://rosettabooks.com/search/node

In IE7, I *can* enter text in the search field in the 'content' area of the page (the advanced search) but I *cannot* enter text in the search field in the navigation bar under the header. I have no problems with firefox/chrome/safari/ie8.

Granted, I am doing some hacky styling css in the problem text field to alter the submit button, but even commenting those out in the css has not seemed to rectify my problem.

Additionally, I can't install the ie developer tools to inspect the css on the windows side and can only use firebug with firefox to try to troubleshoot this.

I've seen similar issues with IE7 that involved re-registering a certain dll, but those cases appear to be for people who cannot enter text at all anywhere, and that is not my problem.  It seems to have something to do with my css, probably css on a parent element, but I can't seem to locate the problem.

Comment: I'm having no problems seeing the problem in the IE8 debugger.  The div "primary-menu" is positioned on top of the text field. IE7 expands divs horizontally sometimes when other browsers don't.

Comment: That Lightbox2 overlay seems to only affect the top section of your website, so maybe that could be causing the problems. Can you interact with the top portion of your site at all?

Comment: Thanks, Pointy.  If I could install IE developer tools here on my corporate machine, I could have probably figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution I found is to add for `#search-box` the following `position:relative;z-index:100`.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the "primary-menu" div a width of 650px or so.  The problem is that that element is positioned above the text input.

There are times when IE7 lets `<div>` elements (well, any block element like that) expand horizontally to fill out to the container width even when the element is positioned specially.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem.  I ended up going with a z-index fix instead of specifying the width of primary-menu.